# Django apps.get_models(): how to load models from other folders

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

All models from `apps/<some_app_name>/models.py` are loaded OK when using `apps.get_models()`, but unfortunately the folders client/brand/reseller/company on the image also have a `models.py` file on each of them, which are not being loaded on `apps.get_models()` (code below):

```py
import pytest
from django.apps import apps


# Set managed=True for unmanaged models. !! Without this, tests will fail because tables won't be created in test db !!
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def __django_test_environment(django_test_environment):
    unmanaged_models = [m for m in apps.get_models() if not m._meta.managed]
    for m in unmanaged_models:
        m._meta.managed = True
```

Can someone explain me how/where should I set pytest/Django to lookup for models?

Using Python 3.9.18, and Django 3.2.21

Not sure if it helps on something: these 4 models inherit from `Account`, and that model inherit from `PolymorphicMPTTModel` (which allows for some pretty crazy/confusing parent-child relations).

Answer (score 0):

Django recognizes these child models if they are imported in `account/models.py` or `account/models/__init__.py`:

```py
from .client import *
from .brand import *
from .reseller import *
from .company impot *

...
```

You can also create new apps that contain `models.py` independently.

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying the path?

```
return apps.get_model("apps/account/client/<YOUR_MODEL_NAME>")
```

or

```
return apps.get_model("account/client/<YOUR_MODEL_NAME>")
```

I'm not sure which is exactly a Django App and how these are defined in your settings so you might have to use one or the other.